# Determine number of all the immediately adjacent points in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have grid of point and want to calculate number of `red` and `blue` point surrounded by each point

for example

For point( X marked )

[image: fig 1]

blue points = 6

red points = 2

I want to calculate it for the whole data set

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    

x = np.linspace(1,50)
y = np.linspace(1,50)

GRID = np.meshgrid(x,y)
grid_colors = 1* ( np.random.random(GRID[0].size) > .8 )
sample_data = pd.DataFrame( {'X': GRID[0].flatten(), 'Y':GRID[1].flatten(), 'grid_color' : grid_colors})

sample_data.plot.scatter(x="X",y='Y', c='grid_color', colormap='bwr', figsize=(10,10))
```

[image]

```
red_points = sample_data[sample_data.grid_color == 1]
blue_points = sample_data[sample_data.grid_color != 1]
```

Comment: if you dont mind me asking what are you going to do with the new dataset ?

Comment: @WaveShaper  it is something related to my PhD work on additive manufacturing and late on I will you these as new features in the N net

Answer (score 2):

`scipy.signal.convolve2d` seems to be perfect fit for this application.

```py
color_matrix = grid_colors.reshape(50, 50)
from scipy import signal
adjacent_boxes = np.array([[1,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,1]])
red_dots = signal.convolve2d(color_matrix, adjacent_boxes, mode='same', boundary='fill')
blue_dots = signal.convolve2d(1 - color_matrix, adjacent_boxes, mode='same', boundary='fill')

red_dots
>>>
array([[1, 2, 2, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 4, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 2, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 2, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 0, ..., 1, 0, 0]])

blue_dots
>>>
array([[2, 3, 3, ..., 5, 5, 3],
       [5, 6, 4, ..., 8, 8, 5],
       [4, 7, 6, ..., 7, 8, 5],
       ...,
       [4, 6, 7, ..., 7, 7, 5],
       [3, 5, 8, ..., 7, 7, 4],
       [2, 3, 5, ..., 4, 5, 3]])

red_dots + blue_dots
>>>
array([[3, 5, 5, ..., 5, 5, 3],
       [5, 8, 8, ..., 8, 8, 5],
       [5, 8, 8, ..., 8, 8, 5],
       ...,
       [5, 8, 8, ..., 8, 8, 5],
       [5, 8, 8, ..., 8, 8, 5],
       [3, 5, 5, ..., 5, 5, 3]])
```

To have it inside dataframe, (thanks to @patrick artner) you can use:

```py
sample_data['red_dots'] = red_dots.flatten()
sample_data['blue_dots'] = blue_dots.flatten()
print(sample_data)
         X     Y  grid_color  red_dots  blue_dots
0      1.0   1.0           0         1          2
1      2.0   1.0           0         2          3
2      3.0   1.0           1         2          3
...    ...   ...         ...       ...        ...
2498  49.0  50.0           0         0          5
2499  50.0  50.0           0         0          3

[2500 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: can I have it in the dataframe where each row represents single point in the grid and 1st col= x axis, 2nd col= y axis, 3rd=blue/red, 4th = adjacent blue pts , 5th=adjacent red pts, I already have first 3 columns

Comment: @mikel check the dims, could be something as easy as `sample_data ["red"] = red_dots.flatten()`

Comment: I have one more issue, since this dataset in the question was only as a reference , I have several data frames with rows 96(grid 12*8), 120(grid 24*5) and so on , in such case how i can convert 3rd column ( grid_colors  ) with grid_colors  into 2d arrays cannot apply `reshape(50, 50)`

Comment: you must provide row and column counts. like `.reshape(num_rows, num_cols)` etc.

Comment: that is what I tried already  but the actual problem is, in some dataframes I have less number of points, then the grid size for example 118 points in (240*5 ) then `.reshape(240, 5)` gives error with 118 points

Comment: also ,1st col= x axis, 2nd col= y axis, show the coordinates of each point and  they are not in the sequence , but  simply doing  .reshape(num_rows, num_cols) will create 2 D array as it is sequenced in the dataframa (col3)

Comment: I can help with this too, but it will be slower. make a copy of df. Then set x and y as indices. Then inc or dec indices according to adjacency. Then combine and sum up all the values. But as I ve said this is way slower. So if you can do, focus on making good data structure. If you can't this is the way to go